# How to get a json value dynamically?

Tags: json, jmeter, jsonpath

in Jmeter, for the message below i want to get the value of tag CC2650HumidityData (or tag name and tag value) but I don't know the name of tag; it is contained in a variable.
I've used this json path:

```
$.message.inputData[*].${tagName}
$.message.inputData[*].vars.get("tagName")
```

but without success.
This is an example of message:

```json
{
    "message": {
        "inputData": [
            {
                "CC2650HumidityData": "51",
                "dateTime": "2020-12-18T08:35:21.342Z"
            },
            {
                "CC2650BarometricPressureData": "21",
                "dateTime": "2020-12-18T08:35:15.136Z"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first option, to wit this one: `$.message.inputData[*].${tagName}` should work just fine

[image]

Just make sure that your `tagName` variable exists and has the anticipated value, it can be done using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/)

Also be aware that you won't be able to use `JSONPath Tester` mode of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener for testing JSONPath queries as it doesn't evaluate variables, you will need to **run** your test to see the variables values (or use this [Dummy Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/DummySampler/) like I did)